# Objectbox notIn with non numeric values

Tags: kotlin, objectbox

We are trying to build a query where we need to check that a non numeric value (an UUID) is not in a collection of UUIDs but the available implementations only accept int and long arrays.

Is there anyway to do this? We have tried using `filter` but it has to be used after the find method and that is not correct since it's a paginated query and that would mean to lose some results